# Ionic Windows App crash Emulator

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing windows app using ionic framework. App working good with Android & IOS but getting crash with windows Emulator 10.0.143xxx. i didn't try with real device yet.

> With Windows Target Version 8.1 :

```
'WWAHost.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (MSAppHost/2.0)'. 
The program '[4164] WWAHost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

With Target version 8.1 app get crash when try to use `select-option` from template page. except that it is working.

> With Target Version 10.0:

App get crash when launch in emulator with error.

```
'WWAHost.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (MSAppHost/3.0)'. 
The program '[4776] WWAHost.exe' has exited with code -1073741189 (0xc000027b).
```

I am already using `meta` in `index.html` are :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

and `$compileProvider` in `app.js` are :

```
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|ghttps?|ms-appx|ms-appx-web|x-wmapp0):/);
$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|ms-appx|ms-appx-web|x-wmapp0):|data:image\//);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, Windows 10 Crash Issue was because of One signal notification plugin : https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4671

try may be some other plugin using at launch activity can be reason of crash.